# How to take the derivative of an eigenvalue equation in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, differentiation, hamiltonian

Equation 2.1 is $$H_0(t)\vert n \rangle = E_n\vert n \rangle$$
Equation 2.8 is $$\langle m \vert \partial_tn \rangle = \frac{\langle m \vert \partial_tH_0 \vert n \rangle}{E_n-E_m}$$
In the following paper http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/42/36/365303, they say that they derive equation 2.8 by taking the derivative of 2.1. I have tried many approaches, without avail. My most recent attempt is as follows:
$$H_0(t)\vert n \rangle = E_n\vert n \rangle$$
$$\partial_t(H_0(t)\vert n \rangle) = \partial_t(E_n\vert n \rangle)$$
$$\partial_tH_0(t)\vert n \rangle + H_0(t)\vert \partial_tn \rangle = \partial_tE_n\vert n \rangle + E_n\vert \partial_tn \rangle$$
Then, I was thinking, $\partial_t\vert n \rangle$ can be written as a bra $\langle m\vert $. So, I applied this to both sides:
$$\langle m\vert\partial_tH_0(t)\vert n \rangle + \langle m\vert H_0(t)\vert \partial_tn \rangle = \langle m\vert\partial_tE_n\vert n \rangle + \langle m\vert E_n\vert \partial_tn \rangle$$
$$\langle m\vert\partial_tH_0(t)\vert n \rangle + \langle m\vert H_0(t) - E_n\vert \partial_tn \rangle = \langle m\vert\partial_tE_n\vert n \rangle$$
$$\langle m\vert\partial_tH_0(t)\vert n \rangle + \langle m\vert H_0(t) - E_n\vert \partial_tn \rangle = \partial_t(E_n)\langle m\vert n \rangle$$

Multiplying the $E$'s in equation 2.8, what we want is:
$$E_n\langle m \vert \partial_tn \rangle - E_m\langle m \vert \partial_tn \rangle= \langle m \vert \partial_tH_0 \vert n \rangle$$

This is as far progress as I have been able to make. Could someone please advise me on how equation 2.8 is being derived in this paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\langle m|\partial_t E_n|n\rangle = (\partial_t E_n)\langle m|n\rangle$.  Now, because $E_m-E_n\ne0$ the eigenstates  $|m\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$ have  a different energies   so we have  $\langle m|n\rangle=0$. Also $\langle m|H_0 = E_m \langle m|$.

Comment: got it ! thank you !